# Python Tank Game

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Tank game using Python, but stuck somewhere. Given below is the game-code:

```
from tank import Tank
tanks = {"a":Tank("Alice"), "b":Tank("Bob"), "c":Tank("Carol")}
alive_tanks = len(tanks)
while alive_tanks > 1:
    print()
    for tank_name in sorted(tanks.keys()):
        print(tank_name, tanks[tank_name])
    first = raw_input("Who fires?").lower()
    second = raw_input("At whom?").lower()
    try:
        first_tank = tanks[first]
        second_tank = tanks[second]
    except KeyError, name:
        print("No such tank!", name)
        continue
    
    if not first_tank.alive or not second_tank.alive:
        print("One of those tanks is dead!")
        continue
    print()
    print("*" * 30)
    first_tank.fire_at(second_tank)
    if not second_tank.alive:
        alive_tanks -= 1
    print()
    print("*" * 30)
for tank in tanks.values():
    if tank.alive:
        print(tank.name, "is the winner!")
        break
```

There is some error being displayed when I run the short program and it goes like this:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax **and error at:**

```
    try:
        first_tank = tanks[first]
        second_tank = tanks[second]
    except KeyError, name:
        print("No such tank!", name)
        continue
```

**highlighting the comma with *red* at:**

```
except KeyError, name:
```

**Given the screenshot for help:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieG9k.jpg

I am not able to proceed due to this confusing error. Your help would be really appreciated and respected. **Given below is the code which I have used for defining *Tank class*:**

```
class Tank(object):

def_init_(self, name):

    self.name = name
    self.alive = True
    self.ammo = 5
    self.armor = 60

my_tank = Tank("Bob")

def_str_(self):

    if self.alive:
        return "%s (%i armor, %i shells)" % (self.name, self.armor, self.ammo)
    else:
        return "%s (DEAD)" % self.name

def fire_at(self, enemy):

    if self.ammo >= 1:
        self.ammo -= 1
        print self.name, "fires on", enemy.name
        enemy.hit()
    else:
        print self.name, "has no shells!"

def hit(self):

    self.armor -= 20
    print self.name, "is hit!"
    if self.armor <= 0:
        self.explode()

def explode(self):

    self.alive = False
    print self.name, "explodes!"
```

Thank you so much in advance; desperate for the answers.

Comment: Well, it's invalid syntax, so have you tried researching how to correctly write an except statement?

Comment: yes, i finally found the cause of the trouble and corrected it within a couple of hours of posting my question... hahahaha :-D...... thanks for taking out your precious time

Comment: applied correction: "except KeyError as name:" and "def __init__(self, name):" and def __str__(self):